# How can the prediction of a model be assessed?

Tags: confidence-interval, predictive-models, prediction, uncertainty

I just played around with the VGG16 and ResNet56 model trained on the ImageNet dataset and realized, after running some tests, that the prediction confidence of both networks is really high even if the classification was wrong. In a supervised context there is the possibility of looking at the label to see if the model's prediction was correct or not. But what about new images that the network has never seen before and where no label exists? What are the possibilities of detecting if the model is really right about its prediction? How can the model's prediction correctly assessed with respect to its correctness? Are there other ways to determine if the model is really certain about its decision?

Comment: Well, if you don't know the ground truth (the label), then you can't assess whether a prediction was correct or not. I don't quite understand your last sentence - you can simply look at the certainty that most models output. Unfortunately, as you note, certainty is not necessarily related to correctness. Can you clarify what you are asking about?

Comment: @StephanKolassa In the last sentence I just wanted to know if there are existing methods that can help to determine if the model's prediction can be trusted or not.

Comment: Well, if you can't compare the model's predictions on *some* holdout sample where you know the ground truth, I don't think there is much you can do...